# Matriz ou Vetor?

Tags: c#, terminologia

Quais as vantagens de usar uma matriz, já que o vetor é mais fácil de usar e faz as mesmas coisas?

Comment: Eu uso List normalmente

Answer (score 9):

Sua afirmação não está correta, eles não fazem a mesma coisa, pode até ser parecidos no fundamento mas são diferentes e definitivamente não fazem a mesma coisa.

De uma maneira muito simples podemos dizer que **vetores** são estruturas de dados uni-dimensionais (uma dimensão) que armazenam dados.

Podemos pensar num vetor como essa representação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a na posição 1 value 11, a na posição 2 vale 15, e assim por diante. Em código poderia ser:

```
a[1] == 11
```

Já uma matriz tem mais de uma dimensão, em geral duas, mas pode ter mais, ou seja o objetivo é ter um par de informações por exemplo, o que não pode ser feito com um vetor.
Aqui uma reapresentação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, na posição 1,1 vale 4, na posição 1,2 vale 16, na posição 2,1 vale 12, e assim por diante, ou em código algo assim:

```
b[1,1] == 4
```

Com isso dá pra perceber a diferença entre as estruturas e notar que uma não faz o que a outra faz, é questão de ver qual cenário aplicar cada uma.

Um exemplo clássico de aulas de programação é aquele que pede "*Entre com 4 notas e calcule a média*". Neste caso, precisamos de um **vetor**, porque é uma dimensão apenas: notas.

Agora para o seguinte caso "*Entre com códigos de 4 alunos, e para cada aluno 4 notas*" temos um cenário de duas dimensões: aluno x notas, ou seja, um exemplo de **matriz**.

Em resumo, a questão não é vantagem, eles tem propósitos diferentes e devem ser usados para o caso que precisam ser aplicados.

Comment: interessante o que você disse na parte "Agora para o seguinte caso "Entre com códigos de 4 alunos, e para cada aluno 4 notas" temos um cenário de duas dimensões: aluno x notas, ou seja, um exemplo de matriz."

Comment: Isso, para esse caso um vetor simples não resolveria, dai para cada caso pode analisar e ver qual a estrutura que vai funcionar

Answer (score 8):

Não tem vantagem alguma se você não precisa da matriz. Não é questão de ter vantagem de uma sobre a outra, este dois tipos de dados não são comparáveis, são para necessidades diferentes. Então dizer que faz a s mesmas coisas está errado, e deveria providenciar exemplo fazendo as mesmas coisas.

O vetor que você está dizendo é para uma sequência de dados e quase sempre resolve o que você quer. Uma matriz tem mais de uma dimensão, então pelo menos tem linhas e colunas (pode ter mais dimensões) e você usa quando precisa disto, caso contrário não usa. Na verdade tudo em computação é assim, você usa o que precisa (quando a pessoa não entende bem o que está fazendo ela usa o que não precisa).

Nem sei se dá para dizer que uma forma seja mais fácil que a outra justamente por não serem comparáveis, mas é para usar sempre o  mais simples que resolve o seu problema e nunca inventar de usar o que não precisa.

Para saber qual usar tem que definir bem qual é o seu problema, quais as necessidades dele, o que é a parte mais difícil da programação, porque decorar sintaxe e copiar códigos prontos é fácil, tomar decisões é que faz a diferença entre quem sabe programar e quem não sabe. E para tomar decisões adequadas precisa ter conhecimento profundo de tudo o que usa, não pode só usar superficialmente.

Em programação comercial geralmente não usamos "matrizes", este é um conceito muito mais usado em programação científica (claro que uma aplicação comercial pode ter uma pequena porção que seja científica). No entanto você pode achar usos conceitualmente errados. Em programação comercial costumamos ter linhas, ou seja, listas, vetores. Pode estar pensando que tem coisas que tem colunas, e sim, é verdade, mas não essas colunas são de tipos, geralmente classes. Então você encapsula as colunas em um tipo específico e joga em um *array*. Programadores ingênuos criariam uma matriz se os tipos fossem homgêneos ou vários *arrays* se fossem heterogêneos.

Como sempre tem que analisar cada caso, não dá para dar uma definição geral. Este pe um dos problemas dos exemplos artificiais, ele passa uma ideia de que algo deve ser feito de um jeito e nem sempre isso é verdade.

## Em C#

Note que você usa o termo  vetor, mas em C# só se usa o termo *array*, eles acabam sendo usados como sinônimos, embora não seja exatamente assim. Entendi que quer saber isto, mas saiba que existe uma classe chamada [`Vector`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O que você está chamando de matriz na verdade em C# é chamado de *array* bidimensional. Existe uma classe chamada [Matrix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), e tem ainda uma estrutura [`Matrix3D`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e [`Matrix4x4`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Seria bom ler a documentação destes tipos para entender melhor seus usos. Acho que a pergunta não se refere a isto e se isto for verdade o termo matriz não deveria ser usado neste contexto.

O *array* bidimensional padrão do C# no fundo é um *array* normal, ou seja, uma sequência de dados, até porque a memória é sempre uma sequência de dados, é linear, não tem uma forma retangular. O acesso como se fosse uma matriz se dá por um cálculo. Se tem duas dimensões você tem basicamente esta fórmula:

```
índice da linha vezes o número de colunas total mais o número da coluna
```

ou

```
lin x totalCol + col
```

Lembrando que isto funciona para linhas e colunas começando em 0 (cuidado porque na matemática costuma começar do 1 e isto pode te enganar quando passa para o código, em C# e quase todas linguagens a posição 1,1 quer dizer segunda linha e segunda coluna enquanto que na matemática quer dizer primeira linha e primeira coluna, por isso é confuso tentar usar o conceito matemático misturado com programação.

Então para visualizar melhor:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        WriteLine(array2D[0, 0]);
        WriteLine(array2D[2, 1]); //2 (linha) * 3 (total de colunas + 1 (coluna) = 7
        var array1D = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        WriteLine(array1D[0]);
        WriteLine(array1D[7]);
        for (int i = 0; i < array2D.GetLength(0); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2D.GetLength(1); j++) Write($"{array2D[i, j]} ");
            WriteLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array1D.Length; i++) Write($"{array1D[i]} ");   }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JoNC3v). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qCtVyU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Bidimenstional.cs).

Note que em certas linguagens seria possível acessar como um *array* unidimensional diretamente na "matriz", C# tem uma proteção artificial para não deixar isto ocorrer, mas no fundo o 7 ali acessaria o 2, 1 normalmente em `array2D` se fosse permitido.

Entenda que o `List` não pode ser usado para isto, apesar dele ter um *array* internamente, não dá para criar uma matriz, dá para criar algo parecido, que é a lista de lista, que seria um *array* de *array*, que é diferente de uma *array* bidimensional, já que o acesso não pode ser feito fazendo essa conta que indiquei acima, e nada garante que será tudo retangular, pode ter linhas com tamanhos diferentes, a não ser que você controle isso no seu algoritmo. Por isso existem outros tipos como `Matrix` já citado, embora ainda não faça sentido comparar com um `List` que é um tipo que permite mudar seu tamanho.

Não há diferença de performance claramente perceptível em relação a uma ou outra (há uma arimética simples que importa quase nada, o tempo de acesso à memória é absurdamente maior e esse cálculo a mais praticamente não faz diferença, ainda que consiga mensurar algo muito pequeno em grandes volumes).

- [Definição matemática de array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array).
- [Definição computacional de array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure).
- [Definição matemática de matriz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)).

Comment: então o vetor e a matriz e usada com o proposito de armazenar mais coisas que uma variavel normal conseguiria por isso eu disse que dão na mesma só que eu tinha duvida se teria alguma diferença quanto a performace ou algo relacionado por que eu acho matriz mais dificil de usar e já vetor eu acho fácil

Comment: @AdrianoRufino editei e falei sobre a performance.